# Chat messages repeated

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I'm trying to create a very simple chat system with socket.io

Here's my html code :

```
<body>
<div id="messages"></div>
<form action="" id="form" autocomplete="off" onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); myScript();">
    <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
</form>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.4/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="client.js"></script>
</body>
```

And this code is called on the submit of the form :

```
var person = prompt("Please enter your name", "Name");

function myScript(){
    var socket = io();
    socket.emit('chat message', person+":"+document.getElementById("m").value);
    document.getElementById("m").value = "";

    socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
        var messages = document.getElementById('messages');
        messages.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<div>'+msg+'</div>');
    });
}
```

The first time i type a message, this one is displayed once. The second time, the message is displayed twice, the third message is displayed three times, and so on.

For some reason, the `socket.on('chat message', function(msg){` is executed multiple times, i just can't understand why

Here's the server code :

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);


app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});


io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
        io.emit('chat message', msg);
    });
});


http.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Any help please ?

Thanks

Comment: What's your server code?

Comment: Oups i forgot to put it. Updated

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

Frontend js :

var person = prompt("Please enter your name", "Name");
var socket = io();

```
function myScript(){
    socket.emit('chat message', person+":"+document.getElementById("m").value);
    document.getElementById("m").value = "";
}
socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    var messages = document.getElementById('messages');
    messages.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<div>'+msg+'</div>');
});
```

The `socket.on('chat message'` shouldn't go in the submit function.

Thanks